# Prolog cut and fail not working as expected

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm learning prolog and I've come across the "cut and fail" combination, and from my understanding they could be used as guard clauses. I've tried experimenting with it but it doesn't work as expected.

```
old(person1).
old(person2).
skilled(person1).
skilled(person2).
skilled(person3).
skilled(person4).
possible_employee(X):-
    old(X),!,fail.
possible_employee(X):-
    skilled(X).
```

In the example above, it should "filter out" `old` people, but it filters out everyone and returns false when querying for a `possible_employee`. Is my code flawed or my understanding of the concept?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you could show what you expect to get, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: @NicholasCarey I'm expecting "possible_employee(X)" to unify X with all persons that are not old and which are skilled (X=person3;X=person4), but I'm getting a simple "false"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(old(X) ; skilled(X)), possible_employee(X)` will do what you want.

`member(X, [person1, person2, person3, person4]), possible_employee(X)` will do what you want.

Your predicate filters *out* solutions. It can't be used in generative fashion, because of the cut. As soon as `old(X)` is fulfilled, the predicate `possible_employee/1` irrevocably fails, as prescribed. So it  must be supplied with some more possibilities, from some outside source. It itself is done at that point.

What your predicate is (re-)implementing, is "`not`", `\+`.

In Prolog, `not` is not *"not"*. It must be read as "can not *prove* that ...".

Under this reading, the meaning of  `possible_employee(X)` is, "can't prove `old(X)`, and can prove `skilled(X)`". But `old(X)` *with the fresh `X`* can *always* be proved, with that knowledge base.

If the clauses order is switched, it completely changes the predicate's meaning. A predicate's (several) clauses are in an implied disjunction, "or":

```
possible_employee(X):-
    skilled(X).
possible_employee(X):-
    old(X),!,fail.
```

means, "can prove `skilled(X)`", and nothing else (do you see why?). So then, under

```
old(person1).
old(person2).
skilled(person1).
skilled(person2).
skilled(person3).
skilled(person4).
possible_employee(X):-
    skilled(X).
possible_employee(X):-
    old(X),!,fail.
```

the call `possible_employee(X)` should succeed four times, for all the four persons. And it does, even though the two of them are also `old/1`.

So you see, the presence of cut changes everything. It makes the predicate's meaning totally dependent on *operational* semantics.

In logic, `A ; B` is the same as `B ; A`. But not *operationally* so.

Bring the cut in, forget the logic, start thinking of operation details of Prolog interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

The conceptual execution model in Prolog is a search tree. Prolog's inference engine does a depth-first, left-to-right search of the tree, looking for solutions (leaf nodes) that match all the constraints in your predicate.

A cut (`!`) eliminates choice points — e.g., it prunes the search tree.

So your `possible_employee/1` predicate

```
possible_employee(X) :- old(X), !, fail.
possible_employee(X) :- skilled(X).
```

will fail *completely* as soon as `old(X)` is satisified. That's what `!, fail` means. Alternative solutions for `old(X)` will not be tried; neither will the second term of the predicate ever be tried.

Prolog is a *descriptive* language: describe your solution in the same you you did in your comment:

> I'm expecting "possible_employee(X)" to unify X with all persons that are not old and which are skilled (X=person3;X=person4).

That leads us to this simple solution, which is pretty much just your problem statement:

```
possible_employee(X) :- % a possible employee is one who
  skilled(X) ,          % - is skilled, and
  \+ old(X)  .          % - is not old
```

`\+/1` is both a unary prefix operator, and a predicate that means "not provable".

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%5C%2B)/1